# What is the value of <object name>.<method name> in Python?

Tags: python, python-object

Consider the following code.

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self, x):
        pass
    
foo1 = Foo()
foo2 = Foo()
foobar1 = foo1.bar
foobar2 = foo2.bar          #What are foobar1 and foobar2?

print(foobar1 is foobar2)   #prints False. Why?
```

On the one hand, I can see why `foobar1` is not `foobar2`–if I call `foobar1(some_arg)` , the call should in general be independent of `foo2` and vice versa. But don't `foobar1` and `foobar2` both refer to function object defined inside the class `Foo`?

Comment: `a is b` tells you if the two names refer to the same object. Why is it surprising that a method of the object `foo1` is not the same as a method of the object `foo2`, knowing that `foo1` and `foo2` are distinct objects and no shenanigans have taken place that would set `foo1.bar = foo2.bar`?

Comment: I don't know much about the semantics of python, but my guess would be that behind the scenes, each `Foo` object contains its own pointer to a single `bar` method. If this were the case, then it would make `foobar1`'s pointer a different object than `foobar2`'s object.

Comment: You'd get the same result even if you used the same `Foo` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `method_name` is actually defined in the class object of `object`'s class, then `<object>.<method_name>` is a "bound method" (or closure), which effectively wraps the function from the class method in order to provide `<object>` as the `self` argument. If `method_name` is actually an attribute of `<object>`, or if it has been marked with the `@staticmethod` decorator, then `<object>.<method_name>` just the function itself.

That's a bit of an oversimplification. There's lots more information in the Python reference manual (for example, in the "Callable objects" section of [Section 3.2, The standard type hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3.12/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), and, iirc, in the Python tutorial. I hope this is a reasonable starting point, but for the nitty-gritty details and a full understanding of all the corner cases, you should probably read the authentic docs.

---

When you call `foobar1` or `foobar2`, you supply one argument and the function gets called with two arguments. How do you suppose that happens?

More specifically, when you call `foobar1`, the method `bar` will be passed `foo1` as the `self` argument, while when you call `foobar2`, the method bar will be passed `foo2`. That seems like magic, but it has a simple cause: when you extracted the `bar` attribute from `foo1` (`foo1.bar`), Python noticed that it didn't come from `foo1` itself; rather, it came from the class `Foo`. Since it came from the class object, Python created a new function closure on the fly in which `self` is bound to `foo1`. Thus, when you later call the closure, the `self` argument is filled in from the closure.

You don't even need `foo2` to see that. Every time you ask for the `bar` attribute of an instance of class `Foo`, you get a new closure. But that doesn't happen when you ask for the `bar` attribute of the class itself. In that case, the attribute `bar` is directly available, and no closure is constructed:

```
>>> foo1.bar is foo1.bar
False
>>> Foo.bar is Foo.bar
True
```

You can see that these are different things:

```py
>>> foo1.bar
<bound method Foo.bar of <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f9c8d8f27b8>>
>>> Foo.bar
<function Foo.bar at 0x7f9c8d8e5c80>
```

The first one is a "bound method" (where `self` has been bound to a value), and the second one is just a garden variety function.

If you try to call `Foo.bar`, you'll notice that you need to supply the self argument yourself, precisely because you're calling a function and not a closure:

```py
>>> Foo.bar(42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
>>> Foo.bar(foo1, 42)
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, you shouldn't expect the methods to be the same (i.e., in the sense of `is`) when you have different `Foo` objects.  Consider

```py
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [11, 12, 13]
append1 = l1.append
append2 = l2.append
```

Clearly, calling `append1` would do something different than calling `append2` so they can't be the same object.

However, this is a red herring.  Even if you used the same `Foo` object, you'd still get different functions:

```py
foo = Foo()
foobar1 = foo.bar
foobar2 = foo.bar
print(foobar1 is foobar2) # False
```

This is due to a minor optimization that the Python compiler performs.  Consider these two functions:

```py
def get_bar(foo):
    return foo.bar

def call_bar(foo):
    foo.bar()
```

Disassembling them with `dis.dis` produces

```
 0 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
 2 LOAD_ATTR                0 (bar)
 4 RETURN_VALUE
```

for `get_bar` and

```
 0 LOAD_FAST                0 (foo)
 2 LOAD_METHOD              0 (bar)
 4 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
 6 CALL_METHOD              1
 8 POP_TOP
10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
12 RETURN_VALUE
```

for `call_bar`.  You can see that the logic of how `foo.bar` is acquired is different.

The reason why is, at rest (so to speak), there is no `foo.bar` function.  There is a `Foo.bar` function which takes a `Foo` object as its first argument.  When you ask Python for `foo.bar` as in `get_bar`, you want it to return to you a function that doesn't already exist.  So, it makes one up for you on the spot (akin to `functools.partial`).  That's why you get different objects each time you ask for `foo.bar`.

However, when you call `foo.bar` as in `call_bar`, the Python compiler knows that you're not interested in the `foo.bar` function itself but only in calling it.  So, it does just that without creating an intermediate function.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is this CPython specific or would it be the same in other implementations?

Comment: I don't know if it's required by the Python standard (I highly doubt it) but I was able to reproduce this behavior on pypy 3.9.

Comment: @DanielWalker: That particular disassembly is different between v3.6, v3.9 and v3.11. It's an implementation detail. (Although the end result is the same, of course.)

Comment: By the way, the optimisation you're talking about (which, imho, is not really directly relevant to the question) was introduced in v3.7. Here's the [issue which explains the optimization](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/70298)